# How to create child part number from parent data in VBA

Tags: excel, vba, for-loop, parent-child

I have two sheets:

- MHT
- TitleHelper

MHT contains product information like:
[MHT Sheet](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7NPxO.png)

and TitleHelper contains variant information like: [TitleHelper Sheet](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Rhzof.png)

and here is what the expected result should be on sheet MHT: [MHT Result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UurgO.png)

---

So to get the expected result we have to compare the specific cells from each row of MHT against TitleHelper

So first we need to match MHT's Pattern1 OR Pattern2 (Col J or Col K) with TitleHelpers Pattern (Col A). So the first item (D123456) has TWO matches for pattern.

The other matching criteria is that the weight on MHT (Col H) needs to be less than or equal to the Maximum Weight and more than or equal to the Minimum Weight of the matching pattern on TitleHelper (Col B & C)

If these criteria are met: For every match i need to insert a row below the original item on MHT and add an asterisk with the child code of the match at the end of the partnumber. So since D123456 had TWO matches and the weight was correct. it adds two rows below it. The first inserted row having the part number "D123456*M" for the first match, and in the second inserted row having the part number "D123456*XL"

If the pattern matches but the weight is not between the minimum and maximum it will just skip the row and not insert anything which is why "H10-101" did not receive a child part number under it.

---

I don't know if this is helpful but here is my attempt at it and i just get stuck on the portion where the for each statement, if statement, and loop interact with each other. as well as incorporating looping through both worksheets.

```
Sub parentCHILD()
Dim childROW As Long
Dim parentROW As Long
Dim childPATTERN As Range
Dim oMAX  As Range
Dim oMIN  As Range
Dim parentPATTERN As Range
Dim parentPATTERN2 As Range
Dim parentWEIGHT As Range
Dim i     As Long

With Sheets("TitleHelper")
    Set childROW = Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
    Set childPATTERN = Range("A" & childROW)
    Set oMAX = Range("B" & childROW)
    Set oMIN = Range("C" & childROW)
End With


With Sheets("MHT")
    Set parentRow = Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
    Set parentPATTERN = Range("J" & parentROW)
    Set parentPATTERN2 = Range("K" & parentROW)
    Set parentWEIGHT = Range("H" & parentROW)

    For i = 1 To childROW
        if parentPATTERN or parentPATTERN2 = childPATTERN and parentWEIGHT <= oMAX and parentWEIGHT >= oMIN then . . .
    Next i
End With

End Sub
```

EDIT: here is the adaptation of @N8's code

```
Sub parentCHILD()
Dim childROWmax    As Long
Dim parentROWmax   As Long
Dim i              As Long
Dim j              As Long
Dim parentPATTERN  As Range
Dim parentPATTERN2 As Range
Dim parentWEIGHT   As Range
Dim childPATTERN   As Range
Dim oMAX           As Range
Dim oMIN           As Range
Dim childCODE      As Range
Dim parentPART     As Range
Dim newPART        As String


    childROWmax = Sheets("TitleHelper").Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
    parentROWmax = Sheets("MHT").Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
    MHTROWmax = Sheets("MHT Result").Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row


    For i = 2 To parentROWmax

        'Increment Result sheet row
        MHTROWmax = MHTROWmax + 1

        'get MHT row info for comparison

           Set parentPATTERN = Worksheets("MHT").Range("J" & i)
           Set parentPATTERN2 = Worksheets("MHT").Range("K" & i)
           Set parentWEIGHT = Worksheets("MHT").Range("H" & i)
           Set parentPART = Worksheets("MHT").Range("A" & i)

        'Write a row to MHT Result Table
        Sheets("MHT").Rows(i).Copy Sheets("MHT Result").Rows(MHTROWmax)

        For j = 2 To childROWmax

            'get TitleHelper row info for comparison
            Set childPATTERN = Worksheets("TitleHelper").Range("A" & j)
            Set oMAX = Worksheets("TitleHelper").Range("C" & j)
            Set oMIN = Worksheets("TitleHelper").Range("B" & j)
            Set childCODE = Worksheets("TitleHelper").Range("F" & j)
            newPART = parentPART & "*" & childCODE

            'Perform if/then
            If (parentPATTERN = childPATTERN _
                Or parentPATTERN2 = childPATTERN) _
               And parentWEIGHT <= oMAX _
               And parentWEIGHT >= oMIN Then

                'Increment Result sheet row
                MHTROWmax = MHTROWmax + 1

                'Criteria is met, write a row to MHT Result Table
                Sheets("MHT").Rows(i).Copy Sheets("MHT Result").Rows(MHTROWmax)
                Sheets("MHT Result").Cells(MHTROWmax, 1) = newPART

            End If
        Next j

    Next i
End Sub
```

Above is the final sub for my worksheet

Comment: Thank for the advice, hopefully thats better.

Comment: Is it fair to say that you want to search for pattern matches between the two sheets and, if they exist, to create additional MHT rows where the Part Number is concatenated with the child code?

Comment: @n8 absolutely spot on, the only other thing is the weight has to be in between the minimum and maximum.

Comment: Your overall attack needed work, hopefully with my suggestion you are over the hurdle.

Comment: I would specify those ranges as values, yes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like this.  A note: this is much more simply accomplished in SQL.  This is a kind of problem that databases were built to solve.

```
Sub parentCHILD()
Dim childROWmax  As Long
Dim parentROWmax As Long
Dim i            As Long
Dim j            As Long

childROWmax = Sheets("TitleHelper").Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
parentROWmax = Sheets("MHT").Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
MHTROWmax = Sheets("MHT Result").Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row

For i = 1 To parentROWmax
    'Increment Result sheet row
    MHTROWmax = MHTROWmax + 1
    'get MHT row info for comparison            
    'Write a row to MHT Result Table
   Sheets("MHT").Rows(i).Copy Sheets("MHT Result").Rows(MHTROWmax)

   For j = 1 To childROWmax

        'get TitleHelper row info for comparison

        'Perform if/then
        If (parentPATTERN = childPATTERN _
            or parentPATTERN2 = childPATTERN) _
           and parentWEIGHT <= oMAX _
           and parentWEIGHT >= oMIN then

          'Increment Result sheet row
          MHTROWmax = MHTROWmax + 1
          'Criteria is met, write a row to MHT Result Table
          Sheets("MHT").Rows(i).Copy Sheets("MHT Result").Rows(MHTROWmax)
          Sheets("MHT Result").Cells(MHTROWmax, 1) = concatValue
        End If
    Next j

Next i
```

Comment: unfortunately i do not have access to Access or other database software

Comment: Also i'm still lost on writing out the loop that inserts the rows below the parent part numbers for each match from the if statement.

Comment: i understand what you did to clean up establishing rowmax and i is the counting variable for parent and j is the counting variable to child. i understand the 'if' part of the statement. i just don't know how to write the 'then' or if it requires a 'do while' or anything like that.

Comment: There are lots of free versions of SQL, maybe just consider it for a learning opportunity.  If you find yourself in complex problems like this just know that there are tools that can help you quickly if you learn them.

Comment: As for your issue, I made some changes to my suggestion that might help!  Let me know if you have any issues please.

Comment: yeah i mean i put a request in to receive even the free MySQL to my IT department but it was denied. So i don't have it available to me at work anyways. I really appreciate seeing your thoughts on the code though. What would be the 'write a row to MHT result table' | | I'm going to add an edit with my newest attempt, but i'm still not grasping the inserting rows and perhaps more that you can point out.

Comment: you might have better luck asking for them to give you access to a sandbox database.  They probably just don't want you to run a server on your own machine, which is legitimate.  you shouldn't do that.  BUT they should be able to give you a playground.

Comment: I made some changes.  Are you using F8 to step through the code or are you just running the macro?

Comment: Do you record macros, or do you just write code and run it?

Comment: I do a mixture of both. If i don't understand the syntax at all i record it. If i understand the syntax i generally just write it and run it. And no i didn't even know i could use f8 to go line by line

Comment: F8 is magic, you can hover over variables to understand what they'll be writing.  It helps you understand what variables contain at runtime.

Comment: For my changes, you need to replace "concatValue" with your own `Part Number/child code` logic.

Comment: gotcha, i will definitely resume experimenting with this on monday, but just in case i'll link a copy to the workbook so you can actually see the data. i ran the code and it did the creating rows part, but it included the headers and i didn't have the if statement values defined, but i appreciate all your help in walking through this with me

Comment: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1_XUVVRVIxEWknr2Qm5Te7whYhQ5W6akO/view?usp=sharing

Comment: Cool.  When you do start this back up, note that you have to write code for the `get MHT row info for comparison` and `get TitleHelper row info for comparison` sections.  That's your `parentPATTERN, childPATTERN, parentPATTERN2, parentWEIGHT, oMAX, oMIN` values.

Comment: I edited my post to show my most recent attempt at making the code work.

Comment: It currently copies over the parent rows like it should, but i don't think the if statement is working because defining the row info as ranges or something? i'm not quite sure. can you take a look at it and tell me where i'm going wrong?

Comment: To start, change your i = 1 and j = 1 to i = 2 and j = 2 to ignore the headers.

Comment: it should show "ah", for every time the if statement is true, in a row below the parent row

Comment: You've got your oMax looking at the "Min" column and vice-versa.

Comment: This is why you should use F8 to step through to debug, you can hover the mouse pointer over variables to see what they are in the code vs what you expect them to be.

Comment: you are so right. wowwww. it works perfectly as intended now, i'll update the code when i have the concatValue written. Thank you so much for your help

Comment: Glad it works!  Now get out there and start looping!